# WPF Expression Blend Theme

Tags: wpf, themes, expression-blend

For my next application i want to use themes to have some eyecandy to provide. So i decided to make my app look like the (dark-themed) Expression Blend if possible. Is there any theme offered i might reuse or am i to start from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please have a look at this

http://wpfthemes.codeplex.com/

This have both Expression Dark and Expression light and other themes available.

Even you can tweak or modify the existing themes